# Solving Js Object property lookup

Tags: javascript

The following function in this code is working for a reason I don't understand. Please can someone explain to me why the second if statement wont work without it being nested in the first. Also why doesn't the first statement need a return.

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (let x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++) {
    if (contacts[x].firstName === name) {
      if (contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[x][prop];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
}

lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

Comment: The second condition works without the first condition but it will _always_ return the first match where the object contains "likes"., The first condition is there to ensure that the name matches.  Comment out the first condition, and replace "Akira" with "Harry". It will return Akira's likes, not Harry's. Uncomment that condition and the likes returned will be Harry's.

Comment: thanks Andy, I think I'm just not understanding why the second if statement must be nested (as I have tried solving this with two separate if statements with their own returns but it didn't work). But after looking at the solution, it says I must use a nested if and it gave me this solution. Here is the link to this challenge: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/profile-lookup

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't realise this was a challenge. Your code is good, and you followed the instructions perfectly. The second condition has to be nested because it needs to return "No such property", and you can't do that if you combine the conditions on one line.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is fundamentally about nesting if statements and `return`, not the specific checks that are being done in each `if` statement, so my answer reflects that assumption.

Fundamentally the if statement checks *something* and when that something is true, it will run some code in brackets.

So when you have 2 nested if statements:

```js
if (a) {
  if (b) {
    return x();
  }
}
```

In the above example, `return x()` will only run if *both* `a` and `b` are true.

If we were to re-organize this:

```js
if (a) {
}
if (b) {
  return x();
}
```

In this case, `return x()` will if `b` is true. `a` has no effect.

In this example:

```js
if (a) {
  return x();
}
if (b) {
  return x();
}
```

Above, `x()` will run if *either* `a` or `b` is true. So if `b` is true, but `a` is false, we will still return.

The intention of your code is to return when *both* conditions are true. Here's a different way to write this:

```js
if (a && b) {
  return x();
}
```

The reason this is *not* done, is because the task requires the second condition to return a specific string 'No such property' if the property did not exist, and ignore the contact and move on to the next contact if the property *did* exist and did not match `name`.

Applying that to our if statement, it basically becomes this:

```js
if (a) {
  if (b) {
    return x();
  } else {
    return "No such property";
  }
} else {
  // Do nothing! this else statement doesn't
  // exist in your code, but I'm adding it in
  // To illustrate that we do nothing if a is
  // false
}
```

There *is* a more elegant way to write this though, we can inverse the 'b' check and return early:

```js
if (!b) {
  return 'No such property';
}
if (a) {
  return x();
}
```

The reason this *is* correct without nesting, is because:

1. If `b` is false, we know for sure that we want to return the error.
2. When we use `return`, the function immediately ends/exits, so there's a guarantee that the `a` check never happens.